# Xcode: How do i print lap time in my stopwatch?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to print the the LapTime i get from calculation on label in Xcode. I want to print different lines at different time.
For eg.
Lap1: 5.456sec
Lap2: 6.011sec
Lap3: 7.110sec

i am able to print one but once a new one comes(lap2) the old lap disappears.I want to keep all laps and it can wrap when there is no further space after may be lap5.Imagine printing laps just like iPhone's stopwatch.

I am using

LapTimelabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%02d %02d %02d ", LapHours, LapMinutes,LapSeconds];

This code prints it on label but when it prints another lap the old one vanishes i want it to appear in the screen with new one.
I am new to Xcode and maybe instead i need to use other things pls advice.
Thanks

Comment: If you want to imitate iPhone's stopwatch, I'd suggest using a table view and populate the rows with your lap times.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should be appending lines to the label:

```
LapTimelabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@ \n %02d %02d %02d ",
                     LapTimelabel.text, LapHours, LapMinutes,LapSeconds];
```

Make sure its multiline, or alternatively use a `UITextView`.